# Joining three tables using sub-query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to join 3 tables to pull out the information in the order displayed below but The Query I tried is only displaying records that exist in the lead_assign table. I know I would have to do a sub query but i am not sure how it would be written. Can someone point me in the right directions? thanks

Format I am looking for:

```
rec_date, source, phone, email, fname lname
```

Table Designs:

[image]

The query that I tried:

```
select
l.rec_date,
l.source,
l.name,
l.phone,
l.email,
l.comments,
u.fname,
u.lname
from leads l
inner join lead_assign la
on l.id = la.lead_id
inner join users u
on la.user_id = u.id
where l.is_deleted=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select
   l.rec_date,
   l.source,
   l.name,
   l.phone,
   l.email,
   l.comments,
   u.fname,
   u.lname
from leads l
   left join lead_assign la
      on l.id = la.lead_id
   left join users u
      on la.user_id = u.id
where l.is_deleted=0
```

This will return all records from the leads table, and only display the u.fname and u.lname where matching rows exists.

Good luck.